# How to change volume level while playing music in python-vlc?

Tags: python, audio, vlc, volume

Tell me how to change volume during playback and not interrupt it?
Perhaps I need to use an additional library?
My code example:

```
import vlc
import time

url = 'http://prem1.rockradio.com:80/bluesrock?749334267be3790147565672'

#define VLC instance
instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1', '--fullscreen')

#Define VLC player
player=instance.media_player_new()

#Define VLC media
media=instance.media_new(url)

#Set player media
player.set_media(media)

#Play the media
player.play()
player.audio_set_volume(50)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think I have an answer for you! Just note that this code is part of a bigger project that I am working on. Some parts of this code won't be formatted to where it would work as-is.

```
import threading
import time
import vlc
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Playlist Player")
root.geometry("700x200")

volume = Scale(root, from_=0, to=100, orient=HORIZONTAL)
volume.set(100)
volume.place(x=150, y=20)
root.mainloop()

player = vlc.MediaPlayer()
media = vlc.Media(dir + playlist + "/" + song)
player.set_media(media)
player.audio_set_volume(100)
player.video_set_scale(0.6)
player.play()
play()

clip = MP3(dir + playlist + "/" + song)
clip_info = clip.info
time.sleep(int(clip_info.length))  # Wait until after the clip has finished

player.stop()

def play():
    volumethread = threading.Thread(target=refreshvolume, daemon=True)
    volumethread.start()

def refreshvolume():
    while True:
        changevolume(volume.get())
        time.sleep(0.1)

def changevolume(volume):
    player.audio_set_volume(volume)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

So what I did here is pretty much make a thread infinitely loop a command to change the volume every 0.1 seconds (I put sleep in there in an attempt to lower the cpu usage). So every tenth of a second, a command would run that would change the volume to whatever the scale was.